# Proving set of register machines that halt before k steps for some input is non-recursive

Tags: turing-machines, computability, logic, undecidability

Given an enumeration of register machines $R_n$ that take a single natural number as input, and a constant $k$, the function $f$ is defined as:

$$
f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \exists m \text{ such that } R_n(m) \text{ halts in } k \text{ steps} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

I'm trying to show that this function is not recursive, but am unsure of how to go about doing so? If anybody could give me any advice I'd be very grateful.

Comment: I have a question, Is there no bound on n? Because if we are working with a universal registrar machine, we should spend a part our computational steps on decoding n. Which mean that n should be less than k. Which makes f recursive.